# js object is undefined inside my function

Tags: javascript

I have a the following JS function:

```
export function createQueryString(obj){
    const Qstring = require('querystring'); 
    const newQuery = Qstring.stringify(obj);
}

export function fetchLocation() {
    let data= {
        name: "Alex",
        family:   "Jones",
        b-date: "19/01/1980",
        email: "example@example.com"
    };

    const queryString = createQueryString(data);
    console.log(queryString );
}
```

`queryString` returns undefined!

and I am not sure why not, how can I make sure that `queryString` return correct value!

Comment: You forgot to return something in your function `createQueryString`. I vote to close this as a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createQueryString() needs to return newQuery -

```
export function createQueryString(obj){
    const Qstring = require('querystring'); 
    return Qstring.stringify(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the `creteQueryString` function does not have a return statement